# Nightwatchjs: How iterate and set elements with hashed id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nightwatch.js

I would like to select multiple elements on a form page that makes use of hashed IDs. The application is made using Vuejs and it hashes certain attribute values being that they are dynamic.

I'd like to run E2E test this page with Nightwatchjs, but I am having trouble finding a away to select the form elements being that they do not have a fixed id attribute.

I've looked into elements() but couldn't quite grab the id. So I've been trying to select them using

```
 .setValue('div.row.form>.formComponent>.input-group:nth-child(3)', 'John Smith')
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "div.row.form>.formComponent>.input-group:nth-child(3)" using: css selector
```

So it seems I'm not using the function properly. I wanted to know what is the best way to grab all the input children of the formComponent and setValues on them.

Comment: You will need to either create a fixed attribute for those elements from within the application or select them by a more stable attribute.

Comment: can you post an example of the hashed id? Is there any part of it that is static? If so you can use css attribute selectors to grab partials but I would need to see an example to show you how to do it. Can you update your post with an html snippet of the elements you are trying to find?